# tar: exclude gzip file, and don't try to gunzip it

Tags: tar, gzip

I would like to skip a large gzip file when I extract a tar file, but everytime tar starts to gunzip it to look inside it seems.

Even when I just try to peek inside tar seems to start gunzipping it, for example:

```
tar -tvf my.tar.gz --exclude="huge_mysql_file.gz"
```

Any tips how to skip entirely that file? I see gzip running when tar gets to that gz file.

Comment: why do you think that tar is gunzipping the file?

Comment: Try `gzip -dc my.tar.gz | tar tf -`.

Comment: It always gets stuck at a large gz file, and when I look at top in another shell window I can see gzip running next to tar.

Comment: I don't really understand you problem here, but it seems that inside that .tar.gz are other .gz files? If that's the case, then the archive is wrong to begin with. a .tar.gz file, is a gziped tar-file, which contains a collection of uncompressed files. Everything else is pretty much done by an idiot.

Comment: As others have pointed out, tar has to read .tar.gz files sequentially, so it can't find out what's after "huge_mysql_file.gz" without reading it in to get to the next file in the archive.  If you need to view the contents of a .tar.gz file frequently, you can always create a text file containing the files list.  e.g. `tar tvzf my.tar.gz > my.tar.gz.list`.  you can then read that .list file with `less` or `grep` it etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`my.tar.gz` is a *gzipped tar* file. *tar* ist short for 'tape archive'. 
So the file `my.tar.gz` has to be unzipped by `gzip -d` before the *tar* file can be read.
There is no random access to the content of a gzip file. I do not really know the gzip file format but at least there is no option for `gzip` to do this. The 'gzip -d' started by `tar` to unzip the `my.tar.gz` file is the `gzip` you can see. `tar` does not decompress the file `huge_mysql_file.gz` but it has to read (and ignore) the file `huge_mysql_file.gz` because this is provided by the pipe to gunzip.

if  the tar file is not gzipped and you list its content like in

```
tar -tvf my.tar --exclude="huge_mysql_file.gz"
```

only the header of `huge_mysql_file.gz` in the archive must be read to know its size. Then tar can skip the file without  reading it and continue on the following file.

Comment: Note that tar cannot do sequential access in this case because the archive is read from a pipe (from gzip), but for a tar in a regular file (uncompressed), it will not read the full content and will skip to the start of each file header in that archive (for `-t` to display the content)

Comment: thx to @sch: I will check this and adjust my answer as soon as possible

Comment: thx again @sch: I rewrote the post and hope now there are no more  errors